# getFirstDayOfWeek not returning the first day of the week

Tags: java, java-8

I'm looking to get a LocalDate for the first day of this week (Sunday) in my Locale (US), but the following code is returning the start of *next* week, what am I missing? I could do `minusWeeks(1)` but that feels like a hack.

```
// returns 4/15 instead of 4/8
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now().with(WeekFields.of(Locale.US).getFirstDayOfWeek());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of java class [DayOfWeek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html)

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now().with(WeekFields.of(Locale.US).getFirstDayOfWeek());
System.out.println(startDate.toString());
```

This returns 2018-04-15 (Today is 2018-04-12 in my Location)

### The reason why it returns the start of next week is

You can check below sentence in `LocalDate.with()` document [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-)

> DAY_OF_WEEK - Returns a LocalDate with the specified day-of-week. The date is adjusted up to 6 days forward or backward within the boundary of a Monday to Sunday week.

And the parameter of `with()` is [ChronoField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) which has variables about `DAY_OF_WEEK`

#### The Thing is it starts Monday (1) to Sunday (7)

> public static final ChronoField DAY_OF_WEEK : This represents the standard concept of the day of the week. In the default ISO calendar system, this has values from Monday (1) to Sunday (7). The DayOfWeek class can be used to interpret the result

Maybe you think Sunday would be 0, the start of week. But the problem is Sunday is not 0 but 7. So, This would be the reason of your problem.